# Adding Google Adwords gclid parameter to Woocommerce order email

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, google-ads-api

I am trying to pass the Google Adwords gclid parameter through the woocommerce checkout, so that I can include it in the confirmation email that we receive when we get an order.

I have managed to find out how to store the gclid parameter in a cookie here:
https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2998031?hl=en (click on "Enable your website and lead tracking system". But I am now stuck on how to get this cookie data in to the order confirmation email, I assume I will have to somehow add a hidden field in to the checkout page and then pass the data to the email, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code which will help you send your data in admin email.
I don't know how you get **Google Adwords gclid parameter** from initially but you can try the following:

You just need to add **Google Adwords gclid parameter** to the echo statement in the code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_customer_details','my_custom_data',10,3);
function my_custom_data( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ){
    if(true==$sent_to_admin){
    echo "the magic code to get Google Adwords gclid parameter";
    }
}
```

Let me know if that worked for you.